# How to Overwrite/Customize wp-admin/nav-menus.php in Wordpress

Tags: menus, walker

I was wondering if is there a way to customize wp-admin/nav-menus.php so that I could add my own extra fields or tab. For example, I want to have a new tab (Menu Settings) created for each menu created by user. I feel it'll be more user friendly if there are specific settings attached to each menu being created. Is that possible? At the moment I'm doing this by theme-options, but it has limitations :(

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with the "add_menu_page" function

you can see example of use on this page : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: Thanks, but I think yo misunderstood or may be I couldn't explain well what I need. I know how to add new menu item to sidebar including any custom slug, but I'm interested to add any extra field/tab inside already created page of wp-admin/Appearance/Menus, so that when a user creates any menu, it can have its relevant custom options. For example, in my premium theme, I want each menu created to have options like menu effect, hover effect, height of menu etc... Means everything that currently premium themes keep in theme options, I want to have Menus related options inside Menus...

Comment: **UPDATE:** 
Okay I have managed it myself by adding custom options on my theme's options panel for each menu created from Menus page of wp.